failure to load an onnx model
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspace/data/extract_features/model_check.py", line 4, in <module>
    model = onnx.load(model_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/onnx/__init__.py", line 170, in load_model
    model = load_model_from_string(s, format=format)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/onnx/__init__.py", line 212, in load_model_from_string
    return _deserialize(s, ModelProto())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/onnx/__init__.py", line 143, in _deserialize
    decoded = typing.cast(Optional[int], proto.ParseFromString(s))
google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message with type 'onnx.ModelProto'

i got some information online. Some said the model was incomplete.But I don't think so.
So I need someone who has the similar experience to help me solve the problem

Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others to provide an answer faster.
Please see: Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?.
